# How to Possible to select last item of listbox by tap on when last item stay under the application bar?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

Listbox contain several items. when i scroll to last item and take initiate to select the item by taping on is not possible cause of that item presence under application bar. Now anybody can say what should i do???  Sample code bellow:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so no sample code huh? :). But judging by the scenario, I think you've not limited the height of your listbox. Set the height so that the listbox's area is limited above the applicationbar.

Answer (score 0):

As PhoBi mentioned, adding code to your post would be more helpful.  however, try this code to limit the size of the listbox:

```
MyListBox.Height = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;
```

you may need to account for other controls' space.  for e.g.:

```
MyListBox.Height = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight - (HeaderStackPanel.ActualHeight);
```